# How to initialize new user account from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-10, user-accounts

I would like to initialize new user account on Windows 10 without login out from admin and login in again to user. Now I create new account with following command:

> net user "username" "password" /add

Next I run some program with command that should load user profile:

> C:> runas /profile /user:user program.exe

However it is not equivalent to the logging as this user. Environment and some folders structures are not prepared without actual logging in. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is the wrong forum for this.  Belongs on superuser

Answer (score 1):

Running a program as the user should be enough to create the profile.
But if it isn't, here's a  Powershell script to create a new profile:
https://gist.github.com/pjh/9753cd14400f4e3d4567f4553ba75f1d

```bsh
<#
.Synopsis
   Rough PS functions to create new user profiles
.DESCRIPTION
   Call the Create-NewProfile function directly to create a new profile
.EXAMPLE
   Create-NewProfile -Username 'testUser1' -Password 'testUser1'
.NOTES
   Created by: Josh Rickard (@MS_dministrator) and Thom Schumacher (@driberif)
   Date: 24MAR2017
   Location: https://gist.github.com/crshnbrn66/7e81bf20408c05ddb2b4fdf4498477d8

   Contact: https://github.com/MSAdministrator
            MSAdministrator.com
            https://github.com/crshnbrn66
            powershellposse.com
#>


#Function to create the new local user first
function New-LocalUser
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $userName,
        # Param2 help description
        [string]
        $password
    )

    $system = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME";
    $user = $system.Create("user",$userName);
    $user.SetPassword($password);
    $user.SetInfo();

    $flag=$user.UserFlags.value -bor 0x10000;
    $user.put("userflags",$flag);
    $user.SetInfo();

    $group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/Users");
    $group.PSBase.Invoke("Add", $user.PSBase.Path);
}

#function to register a native method
function Register-NativeMethod
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$dll,

        # Param2 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]
        $methodSignature
    )

    $script:nativeMethods += [PSCustomObject]@{ Dll = $dll; Signature = $methodSignature; }
}
function Get-Win32LastError
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param($typeName = 'LastError')
 if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]$typeName).Type)
    {
    $lasterrorCode = $script:lasterror | ForEach-Object{
        '[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
         public static extern uint GetLastError();'
    }
        Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public static class $typeName {
            $lasterrorCode
        }
"@
    }
}
#function to add native method
function Add-NativeMethods
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param($typeName = 'NativeMethods')

    $nativeMethodsCode = $script:nativeMethods | ForEach-Object { "
        [DllImport(`"$($_.Dll)`")]
        public static extern $($_.Signature);
    " }

    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public static class $typeName {
            $nativeMethodsCode
        }
"@
}

#Main function to create the new user profile
function Create-NewProfile {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$UserName,

        # Param2 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]
        $Password
    )

    Write-Verbose "Creating local user $Username";

    try
    {
        New-LocalUser -username $UserName -password $Password;
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
        break;
    }
    $methodName = 'UserEnvCP'
    $script:nativeMethods = @();

    if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]$MethodName).Type)
    {
        Register-NativeMethod "userenv.dll" "int CreateProfile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,`
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,`
         [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath, uint cchProfilePath)";

        Add-NativeMethods -typeName $MethodName;
    }

    $localUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$UserName");
    $userSID = $localUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]);
    $sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder(260);
    $pathLen = $sb.Capacity;

    Write-Verbose "Creating user profile for $Username";

    try
    {
        [UserEnvCP]::CreateProfile($userSID.Value, $Username, $sb, $pathLen) | Out-Null;
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
        break;
    }
}

function New-ProfileFromSID {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$UserName,
        [string]$domain = 'PHCORP'
    )
    $methodname = 'UserEnvCP2'
    $script:nativeMethods = @();

    if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]$methodname).Type)
    {
        Register-NativeMethod "userenv.dll" "int CreateProfile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,`
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,`
         [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath, uint cchProfilePath)";

        Add-NativeMethods -typeName $methodname;
    }

    $sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder(260);
    $pathLen = $sb.Capacity;

    Write-Verbose "Creating user profile for $Username";
    #$SID= ((get-aduser -id $UserName -ErrorAction Stop).sid.value)
  if($domain)
   {
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($domain, $UserName)
        $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $SID = $strSID.Value
   }
   else 
   {
       $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName)
       $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
       $SID = $strSID.Value
   }
    Write-Verbose "$UserName SID: $SID"
    try
    {
       $result = [UserEnvCP2]::CreateProfile($SID, $Username, $sb, $pathLen) 
       if($result -eq '-2147024713')
       {
           $status = "$userName already exists"
           write-verbose "$username Creation Result: $result"
        }
        elseif($result -eq '-2147024809')
        {
            $staus = "$username Not Found"
            write-verbose "$username creation result: $result"
        }
       elseif($result -eq 0)
       {
           $status = "$username Profile has been created"
           write-verbose "$username Creation Result: $result"
       }
       else
       {
          $status = "$UserName unknown return result: $result"
       }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
        break;
    }
    $status
}
Function Remove-Profile {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$UserName,
        [string]$ProfilePath,
        [string]$domain = 'PHCORP'
    )
    $methodname = 'userenvDP'
    $script:nativeMethods = @();

    if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]"$methodname.profile").Type)
    {
      add-type @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace $typename
{
    public static class UserEnv
    {
        [DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DeleteProfile(string sidString, string profilePath, string computerName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetLastError();
    }

    public static class Profile
    {
        public static uint Delete(string sidString)
        { //Profile path and computer name are optional
            if (!UserEnv.DeleteProfile(sidString, null, null))
            {
                return UserEnv.GetLastError();
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
"@
    }

   #$SID= ((get-aduser -id $UserName -ErrorAction Stop).sid.value)
   if($domain)
   {
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($domain, $UserName)
        $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $SID = $strSID.Value
   }
   else 
   {
       $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName)
       $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
       $SID = $strSID.Value
   }
    Write-Verbose "$UserName SID: $SID"
    try
    {
        #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949002/c-sharp-delete-user-profile
       $result = [userenvDP.Profile]::Delete($SID)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
        break;
    }
    $LastError
}

Export-ModuleMember Create-NewProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
net users /add name password
```

And to add it to administrators use

```batch-file
net localgroup administrators /add name
```

For example, to add user `test` with password `123456789`

```batch-file
net users /add test 123456789
```

and to add `test` to administrators

```batch-file
net localgroup administrators /add test
```

Note that this has to be run in administrator cmd and creates *local* accounts.

For more help run `net users /?` or `help net users` in cmd.

To do this in powershell, you could also do this:

```batch-file
New-LocalUser -Name "Name" -Password "Password" -AccountNeverExpires -FullName "NameName"
```

This will create a new user account that doesn't expire with the name `Name` password `Password` and full name (file explorer stuff and abbreviations) `NameName`. Also requires administrators.

These examples will initialize the new user as you can see by checking `net users` again in powershell or cmd. These will also already create the new user directories.

Your issue is that you are attempting to start the program ***as that user's environment*** which has not been setup so to run as that user simply use

```batch-file
runas /env /profile /user:user program.exe
```

With the added `/env` switch

See `runas /?`

> ```
> /env              to use current environment instead of user's.
> ```

If I create user `test` with

```batch-file
net users /add test 123456789
```

You can see that they will be in the results of the `net users` query and `net localgroup users` query. You will also see that their user folder will have been initialized

```batch-file
cd %homepath%\..
dir
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-ABCD

 Directory of C:\Users

06/20/2020  10:05 PM    <DIR>          .
06/20/2020  10:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/18/2020  01:15 PM    <DIR>          Neko
03/14/2020  09:16 PM    <DIR>          Public
06/20/2020  10:05 PM    <DIR>          test
```

Something must have to run in that user before it becomes truly initialized.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1, https://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html, `get-help New-LocalUser -full` in powershell, `net user /?` and `runas /?` in cmd.